# Why are questions and answers editable forever but comments get locked in?

Tags: discussion

Is this just for ease of implementation of the site or is there some philosophical reason that comments should be stuck with a typo, mis-wording, or negative tone?

Comment: I don't have anything authoritative on this, but I get the impression that comments are intended to be temporary, aimed at improving the Q or A.

Comment: What Jeff said. Also, comments tend to be followed up with more comments. You would possibly be able to invalidate a series of comment replies by editing an initial comment that these replies reference. This would lead to a comment thread that would be exceedingly difficult, or confusing, to follow. If you can't spot an error within 5 minutes, then it probably wasn't so important.

Comment: If you come across ones that are really bad you can flag us to fix them. Don't abuse this but mods can edit them.